# log4j 2 возвращает NullPointerException

Tags: java, log4j

Доброго времени суток!

Сделал всё в точности как описано в данном мануале: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/flowtracing.html

Подключал: log4j-api-2.0-beta1.jar

xml-файл занес в пакет по умолчанию и назвал log4j2.xml.

При запуске в методе LogManager.getLogger(TestService.class.getName()); выбрасывается NullPointerException.

Никак не могу понять с чем это связано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Надо было всего лишь подключить ещё log4j-core-2.0-beta1.jar